# How to get Wikipedia image by title?

Tags: javascript, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to get Image from wikipedia by title, for example I have a image title `File:Island of Ireland location map Dublin.svg`, and I also know the page id `1642839`. Any way to get the image url/link?

Comment: This is not very clear. Are you starting from a Wikipedia article and you want to get the main image link OR are you starting from an image link and you want the correct file URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Api You can.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info|extracts|pageimages|images&inprop=url&exsentences=1&titles=india
```

`prop=pageimages`

Prop plays an important role.if you want image description, you can get it by `prop=pageimages|pageterms`

we can also get the original image using `piprop=original`

or if you want in thumbnail size image, you can get it using `piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=500`
if the size height/width=500

if we want to request in Json format, we should always use `formatversion=2` in the Api Query.

**Original Image Size**

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&prop=pageimages|pageterms&piprop=original&titles=Albert Einstein
```

**Thumbnail Image Size**

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&prop=pageimages|pageterms&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=500&titles=Albert Einstein
```

We can fetch the specific data using Api and by Modifying it too On Web and Mobile Apps.

Comment: You can't really get a specific image url through that though if there are many images on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in redirect `?title=Special:Redirect/file/` for that.
You don't even need to know which page the image is used in, just enter the filename.

For your file example on English Wikipedia, use: [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Redirect/file/File:Island of Ireland location map Dublin.svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Redirect/file/File:Island%20of%20Ireland%20location%20map%20Dublin.svg)

Read more at [the Mediawiki help for directly linking to an image](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images/sv#Directly_linking_to_an_image).

Answer (score 0):

Say we are starting from the title "County Dublin".

1. First use this API call:

   ```
   https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&format=json&redirects=1&titles=County_Dublin
   ```

   for retrieving the Wikidata item id [`Q173500`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q173500).
2. Then use a second API call:

   ```
   https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q173500.json
   ```
3. Now you can access the JSON object like this:

   `obj['entities']['Q173500']['claims']['P242'][0]['mainsnak']['datavalue']['value']`

   for obtaining the value of the [property P242](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P242), that in this case is `Island of Ireland location map Dublin.svg`;

This allows you to have a **unique** and **relevant** image for your article.

P.S. You can do the same with other properties, such as [P18](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P18) or [P2716](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2716).